# rails server wont start due to will_paginate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, neo4j

I am trying to use Neo4j with JRuby on my system. I followed this [guide](http://blog.rubyrockers.com/2011/03/rails3-application-jruby/), but I get the following error when I try to start up the server. I've required the will_paginate gem in the application.rb so I dont know whats causing the server to fail to start up.

Thanks in advance!

```
    LoadError: no such file to load -- will_paginate/finders/base
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /home/maulin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@brtr/gems/neo4j-1.1.0-java/lib/neo4j.rb:12
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /home/maulin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@brtr/gems/neo4j-1.1.0-java/lib/neo4j.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /home/maulin/projects/brtr/config/application.rb:28
      tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1803
   (root) at /home/maulin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@brtr/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at script/rails:6
```

This is what my application.rb looks like

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'will_paginate'
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require 'neo4j'


# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module Brtr
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
    # config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable Neo4j generators, e.g:  rails generate model Admin --parent User
    config.generators do |g|
      g.orm             :neo4j
      g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture => false
    end

    # Configure where the neo4j database should exist
    config.neo4j.storage_path = "#{config.root}/db/neo4j-#{Rails.env}"

  end
end
```

gem list --local

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.9)
actionpack (3.0.9)
activemodel (3.0.9)
activerecord (3.0.9)
activeresource (3.0.9)
activesupport (3.0.9)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.17)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
neo4j (1.1.0 java)
orm_adapter (0.0.5)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.9)
railties (3.0.9)
rake (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.9.1)
rspec (2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.6.1)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
will_paginate (3.0.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j.rb does not work with the new release of will_paginate 3.0.0
I have updated the neo4j to have a dependency to version 3.0.pre4, see https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/commit/fb86d975da1034fde3a3828b5f6e511f7460e09a

Answer (score 0):

Why are you require-ing will_paginate in your application.rb file?  Also line 28 is a comment in that file, are you sure they both match up?  Can you move that will_paginate?

Oh and I didn't see you report this on will_paginate's issue tracker on github, and what the heck is neo4j and why Jruby... that's all i got :-)

Comment: Neo4J is a graph database gem and its only for JRuby so I didnt have much of a choice. What file are you referring to when you say, line 28 is a comment?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that Neo4J has a dependency on will_paginate

Comment: is it possible that this Neo4J thing isn't up to date with today's launch of will_paginate?  or did they keep up with the 3.0 pres?  If not, they'd be using 2.x which won't work with rails 3... also assuming that from the application.rb file, it's also rails 3, but wasn't mentioned.

Comment: It might have something to do with the new release today. I switched back to 3.0.pre2 and it seems to work.

Comment: you know i looked in the source for that file, and i couldn't find it... but i didn't look through all the classes but i'm sure he'd separate that into the right file if he wanted. now just the matter of accepting this answer... :-)